# When $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{h(\theta)} r drd\theta$ represents an area and when a volumn?

Tags: calculus, integration

Q: When $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{h(\theta)} r drd\theta$ represents an area and when  a volumn?

We often say that an area of a region equals $\iint dxdy = \iint rdrd\theta$. We just need to convert the cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate. Simple enough.

The following is my understanding. I've been doing calculus with this belief for several years but might not be correct.

$\iint f(x,y) dxdy$ represents the volume of an object with its height at  $(x,y)= f(x,y)$.

A double integral of the polar coordinate system can also represent a volume. However, how do you visualize a double integral,  for example, like this?
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{5 + cos3\theta}}r drd\theta$$

I'm suspecting this integral returns a volume of some sort.  I derived this formula by the equation of a deltoid with inner circle with length 1 and the outer circle of length 3. $r(\theta) = <2\cos\theta+\cos2\theta, \sin\theta-\sin2\theta>$

This integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{|r(\theta)|}r drd\theta$$. This is obviously more than the area of the deltoid in 2D space because the area of the deltoid's function should be $2\pi$ and this integral returns more than $2\pi.$

How do you interpret this integral?